# SQL: ERD diagram - data redundancy.

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I showed my lecturer my database today (based on an Ecommerce site).

He was very quick to point out a few issues, such as data redundancy. For example I have User ID in five tables.

My database is based on my ERD: http://imgur.com/X02JlF3

I am just looking on some advice on cleaning up my ERD so that I can produce a more efficient database.

If I removed User ID from every table except Users, how could I provide a User ID with a transaction report for example? Or would User ID need to be a foreign key in every table?

Thanks, sorry if this is an inappropriate question! Just not sure the right way to clean up this ERD.

Comment: regarding `user_id`  you need those , You arent not repeating `user_id` you are linking table using a foreign key fk

Comment: I think he/she is implying you should use a surrogate key.  What happens if someone wants to change their userID? you have to change it in all the tables.  a surrogate key you wouldn't.  You may still need to make userID unique..

Comment: @xQbert Yes, he mentioned that if I wanted to update a product name it would need to be done in a few tables.

Comment: That may not necessarily be a bad thing.  If you expire products and remove them, someone may still want it on their wishlist, but the description is now gone.  If that's the use case you're trying to account for by having product name in the wishlist table I think that's ok.  Database design is about understanding requirements as well.  So if the need is that you would remove products (why I don't know) then having name elsewhere isn't all bad.  Plus if product names change, the wishlist woudln't.... should it? it wasn't that name when we added it to wish list! Just food for thought.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks. I hadn't considered keeping the same name for a product in the wishlist, as when the user added. That wasn't by intention with the ERD, more so turning a slight mistake into usefulness through creative thinking. This is my first big (relatively) database project so I'm trying to get my head around a few things. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, I think that the use of UserID as a foreign key is OK. The redunancy I see is more like Prodcut Name, product Description, Price and stock level occuring in the Wish List, for example. These values should only be in the Product table and the ProductID in Wish List used to join to that table as a FK. With that in mind, I'm sure you will see other examples in your ERD.

Comment: Thank you. I've removed some items now to come up with this: http://imgur.com/vS2tHKc . I think it's better now. I'm just a bit confused by the wish list table for example, it only has two primary keys. Granted the primary key allows us to access the product table for product information, but no actual list is stored.

Comment: I could be wrong, but how do you know what was sold?  I don't see anything in structure with product_ID sales usually have a header for billing total cost etc... and details for individual items, discounts, quantities, etc...

Comment: Sale table was sale id, quantity, date, time, total price and tradactionID as foreign key. Should I add product ID as a foreign key, this would allow the sale table to access product information?

Comment: @joemartin - The rows of Wish List for a UserId *are* the list of Products that the user has added to the wish list. A simple select from that table will give a list of the ProductIDs. A select with join to the Product table will give the Name, Price, etc.